# NumberRangeFilter and NumberRangeFilterBuilder

Tags: google-gadget

I am totally new to apps and some help.

When I use either of this function with awesome table they return the their names with the field title. If am using them to filter "Age", for example, the title in the table and on the search field label shows: "Age NumberRangeFilter" or "Age NumberRangeFilter Builde".

Comment: It is a little hard to figure out what you are trying to ask here.  Maybe it would help to include a code example or try to explain a little more detail about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Was looking at your post as I have the same problem, found no answers so worked it out myself eventually.

Your spreadsheet cell could be formatted as a number stored as text, or that was my problem. I reformatted the column as a number and it worked. You should know it is a number when it is right justified.